# Data structure for regular expressions

Tags: regex, data-structures

How would you guys solve the following problem: A REST API has a lot of functions with different parameters. All of these functions are attached to a callback but the URL contains parameters in the path. For example /user/{name}/surname/{othername}. This results in a regular expression like this /user/*/surname/*. I can store these in a map and start matching the whole map when a request comes in to find the handler.

Is there a faster way to to this than iterating over the whole data structure or isn't it worth to worry about the runtime for around 100 API calls?

Comment: Regular expressions ? Name the language/engine, and please give concrete examples. It is a given that regex is a _separate_ and complex language.

Comment: It's C++ with std::regex

Comment: I believe you're not getting reply's because it is not clear what you are trying to match. `/user/{name}/surname/{othername}. This results in a regular expression like this /user//surname/. I can store these in a map and start matching` doesn't help.

Comment: Ok then question is: Is there a data structure like a map where I can insert a key which is a regular expression and search with a string which is no a regular expression?